# How to efficiently select data in ranges from a postgresql table, when ranges are defined in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

With example tables:

```
create table user_login (
user_id integer not null,
login_time numeric not null, -- seconds since epoch or similar
constraint unique(user_id, login_time)
);

create table user_page_visited (
page_id integer not null,
page_visited_at numeric not null -- seconds since epoch or similar
);
```

with example data:

```
> user_login
  user_id login_time
1       1        100
2       1        140

> user_page_visited
  page_id page_visited_at
1       1             100
2       1             200
3       2             120
4       2             130
5       3             160
6       3             150
```

I wish to return all rows of `user_page_visited` that fall into a range based off `user_login.login_time`, for example, return all pages accessed within 20 seconds of an existing login_time:

```
> user_page_visited
  page_id page_visited_at
1       1             100
3       2             120
5       3             160
6       3             150
```

How would I do this efficiently when both tables have lots of rows? For example, the following query does something similar (returns duplicate rows when ranges overlap), but seems to very slow:

```
select * from
user_login l cross join
user_page_visited v
where v.page_visited_at >= l.login_time
and v.page_visited_at <= l.login_time + 20;
```

Comment: you could try `where v.page_visited_at between l.login_time and l.login_time + 20;`  but I think this will always be slow,

Comment: you could also try a full join instead `on` instead of `where`

Comment: I'm also assuming you've got indexes on those two time columns.

Comment: numeric? - bigint might be better suited, or timestamptz

Comment: It depends on your data distribution, but an index on `user_page_visited.page_visited_at` is likely to help.

Answer (score 1):

First, use regular `join` syntax:

```
select *
from user_login l join
     user_page_visited v
     on v.page_visited_at >= l.login_time and
        v.page_visited_at <= l.login_time + 20;
```

Next, be sure that you have indexes on the columns used for the `join`. . . `user_login(login_time)` and `user_page_visited(page_visited_at)`.

If these don't work, then you still have a couple of options.  If the "20" is fixed, you can vary the type of index.  There are also tricks if you are only looking for one match between, say, the login and the page visited.

Comment: Thanks, your point of using the join syntax and indices is taken, but I was kind of hoping that I could just directly concatenate a range condition from the values in `login_time`, and use that as a filter on `user_page_visited` without doing a join operation.

Comment: @Alex . . . If it met your needs, you could round or truncate the time to every 20 units and use an equijoin.

Comment: I don't think I can round the time units so that an equijoin is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on the comments of the answer from Gordon Linoff.

First we retrieve the tuples that were accessed in the same time slice as a user connection or in the following time slice using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT page_id, page_visited_at
FROM user_login
INNER JOIN user_page_visited ON login_time::INT / 20 = page_visited_at::INT / 20 OR login_time::INT / 20 = page_visited_at::INT / 20 - 1;
```

We now need indexes in order to get a good query plan:

```
CREATE INDEX i_user_login_login_time_20 ON user_login ((login_time::INT / 20));
CREATE INDEX i_user_page_visited_page_visited_at_20 ON user_page_visited ((page_visited_at::INT / 20));
CREATE INDEX i_user_page_visited_page_visited_at_20_minus_1 ON user_page_visited ((page_visited_at::INT / 20 - 1));
```

If you EXPLAIN the query with these indexes, you get a BitmapOr on two Bitmap Index Scan operations, with some low constant cost. On the other hand, without these indexes you get a sequential scan with a way higher cost (I tested with tables of ~100k tuples each).

However this query gives too much results. We need to filter it again to get the final result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT page_id, page_visited_at
FROM user_login
INNER JOIN user_page_visited ON login_time::INT / 20 = page_visited_at::INT / 20 OR login_time::INT / 20 = page_visited_at::INT / 20 - 1
WHERE page_visited_at BETWEEN login_time AND login_time + 20;
```

Using EXPLAIN on this query shows that PostgreSQL still uses the Bitmap Index Scans.

With ~100k rows in user_login and ~200k rows in user_page_visited the query needs ~1.4s to retrieve ~200k rows versus 3.5s without the slice prefilter.
(uname -a: Linux shepwork 4.4.26-gentoo #8 SMP Mon Nov 21 09:45:10 CET 2016 x86_64 AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux)